# Possible to display all files in the current dir with a filename that does not start with an even digit followed by any alphabetic letter?

Tags: command-line, bash, wildcards, echo

I am attempting to answer this problem for a COSC class that focuses on Linux/Unix.

I am using Linux with bash shell. I am new to Linux as of September.

My instructor has this question in this week's assignments and based on class discussions, it goes from being included, to not. I'd really like to nail this after all the time I've spent on it.

The command I've come up with doesn't take into account if a file has a name starting with a even digit followed by another digit using wildcards. This is the sticking point with the question being included or excluded from the assignment and I've sat for hours trying to solve this.

Is it even possible?

I came up with:

```
echo [!02468][a-zA-Z]*
```

Any suggestions are welcomed and greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do the following

```
shopt -s extglob
echo !([02468][a-zA-Z]*)
shopt -u extglob
```

You need to enable `extglob` with `shopt -s extglob` first.
Afterwards you can disable it again with `shopt -u extglob`.

The extglob shell option gives you more powerful pattern matching in the command line.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible with a simple command. The following should do the trick though:

```
for i in *; do
  case "$i" in
    [02468][a-zA-Z]*) ;; # do nothing
    *) echo "$i" ;;
  esac
done
```

Comment: I actually just figured it out just now!

echo [02468][0-9]* | xargs echo [!02468][a-zA-Z]*

Thank you for your reply. You got me to think in a different direction!

Comment: This dosn't work at all. If there is no file matching [02468][0-9]* it will be passed literally to xargs and appear in the output. And files like 2.txt would be missed. And files like 11.txt would be missed.

Answer (score 0):

the following should do the trick

```
echo !([02468][a-zA-Z])
```

Comment: not a valid command in bash

Answer (score 0):

@Rik's solution using `extglob` is probably the best way for `bash`. If you need a shell agnostic way (assuming you are using GNU find), try this:

```
find . -type f -not -name "[02468][a-zA-Z]*"
```